# Help identifying pubkey format

Tags: public-key

A client has requested us to setup SSL certificate public key pinning for an internal desktop application we are developing for them. They have requested us to pin a specific pubkey but we are not aware of what format it is in.

The pubkey provided is `WY*Nhx$kk@PTTz7Ykp*t!q#*8taRR84ZnyT7Rjqc%^29!7zx5GdYa!HSmpM^KQ!D`. Any hints to what format its in is greatly appriciated.

Comment: If you're not sure what format it is, then ask them provide a PEM-encoded SubjectPublicKeyInfo ASN.1 data structure. This is industry standard practice.

Comment: Please ask the person that provided the public  key instead. We're not going to guess. I can tell you that it is probably base 91, which could indicate a concatenated X and Y coordinates of 192 bits each (as the result of decoding is 48 bytes).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes If it's an uncompressed ECC point, then there should've been a byte with the value 0x04 at the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, true, but I've seen encodings without that byte. Anyway, we can only guess which is why I closed it.

Comment: I see, and thank you.